# I don't understand Keras function "fit"

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, training-data, tf.keras

When I was building a DataGenerator and trying to fit it into a model, it didn't work. So I've taken a look into the Keras function 'fit' directly. But I don't understand what this down below code is meaning especially backslash sign. May I ask what this code is for and how that works?

```
with self.distribute_strategy.scope(), \
         training_utils.RespectCompiledTrainableState(self):
      # Creates a `tf.data.Dataset` and handles batch and epoch iteration.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know, the "\" is just there for the ***linebreak***

Comment: Shouldn't that be "\" instead of "" ?

Comment: yeah it should...don´t know why it wasn´t printed :(

Answer (score 1):

As @Seitanist mentioned, it is just a line continuation.

Copying from [python docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> The Python standard library is conservative and requires limiting
> lines to 79 characters (and docstrings/comments to 72).
>
> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied
> line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines
> can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in
> parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash
> for line continuation.
>
> Backslashes may still be appropriate at times.
> For example, long, multiple with-statements cannot use implicit
> continuation, so backslashes are acceptable:

```
with open('/path/to/some/file/you/want/to/read') as file_1, \
     open('/path/to/some/file/being/written', 'w') as file_2:
    file_2.write(file_1.read())
```